# Get text that is within brackets with single or double quotes

Tags: php, regex

I try to found in my all PHP files the strings inside the i18n functions. Here is an example:

```
$string = '__("String 2"); __("String 3", __("String 4"));' . "__('String 5'); __('String 6', __('String 7'));";

var_dump(preg_match_all('#__\((\'|")([^\'"]+)(\'|")\)#', $string, $match));
var_dump($match);
```

I wanna get this result:

```
array
    0 => array
       0 => string 'String 2' (length=8)
       1 => string 'String 3' (length=8)
       2 => string 'String 4' (length=8)
       3 => string 'String 5' (length=8)
       4 => string 'String 6' (length=8)
       4 => string 'String 7' (length=8)
```

But unfortunately I get this result

```
array
    0 => array
        0 => string '__("esto es una prueba")' (length=24)
        1 => string '__("esto es una prueba 2")' (length=26)
        2 => string '__("prueba 4")' (length=14)
        3 => string '__('caca')' (length=10)
        4 => string '__('asdsnasdad')' (length=16)
    1  => array
        0 => string '"' (length=1)
        1 => string '"' (length=1)
        2 => string '"' (length=1)
        3 => string ''' (length=1)
        4 => string ''' (length=1)
    2 => array
       0 => string 'esto es una prueba' (length=18)
       1 => string 'esto es una prueba 2' (length=20)
       2 => string 'prueba 4' (length=8)
       3 => string 'caca' (length=4)
       4 => string 'asdsnasdad' (length=10)
    3 => array
       0 => string '"' (length=1)
       1 => string '"' (length=1)
       2 => string '"' (length=1)
       3 => string ''' (length=1)
       4 => string ''' (length=1)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=\(["\']).*?(?=[\'"])/', $subject, $result, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$result = $result[0];
```

Simple.

Note that I am using **(** as an entry point to the match. If you have more exotic input you should provide it.

Comment: @toledorobia No problem. Just take heed on the notes! :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't capture the *quotes*.

```
preg_match_all('#__\([\'"]([^\'"]+)[\'"]\)#', $string, $match);
```

Also take a look at the *flags* parameter for [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/preg_match_all) for different output formats.

Comment: Thanks... Almost perfect... but the regex ignore **String 3** and **String 6** because there is a comma after the closing quotation marks...